# Wondering why my javascript file isn't loading when I run phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, phonegap

Let me know if I have to post this a different way, but I uploaded the three files I am working with. I am pretty new to jQuery and javascript but in my class I am supposed to be able to get this combination of files running and what is supposed to be happening when I run this HTML file is that when I hit "Submit" on the bottom of the form without entering anything into the text areas, it should return an error message and a little exclamation mark.

Currently, it isn't returning anything at all. The .css file loads fine and changes my form to look like what it is supposed to, but not the .js file. I am wondering if it has something to do with the script tags in the head section of the html file?

For context, I did write most of this myself from the book instructions but apparently the school provided the completed code in separate files which was formatted much cleaner than mine, so I just replaced mine with what you see here. The main section that wasn't clarified on either in the book or by my professor (good luck, he doesn't answer emails) is the information to load Jquery/javascript files in the header section. I am using phoneGap to emulate this web page.

```js
var errors = {};

function displayErrors() {
    // initialise variables
    var haveErrors = false;
    
    // remove the invalid class for all inputs
    $(":input.invalid").removeClass("invalid");
    
    // iterate through the fields specified in the errors array
    for (var fieldName in errors) {
        haveErrors = true;
        $("input[name='" + fieldName + "']").addClass("invalid");
    } // for
    
    // if we have errors, then add a message to the errors div
    $("#errors")
        .html(haveErrors ? "Errors were found." : "")
        .css("display", haveErrors ? "block" : "none");
} // displayErrors

function displayFieldErrors(field) {
    var messages = errors[field.name];
    if (messages && (messages.length > 0)) {
        // find an existing error detail section for the field
        var errorDetail = $("#errordetail_" + field.id).get(0);

        // if it doesn't exist, then create it 
        if (! errorDetail) {
            $(field).before("<ul class='errors-inline' id='errordetail_" + field.id + "'></ul>");
            errorDetail = $("#errordetail_" + field.id).get(0);
        } // if
        
        // add the various error messages to the div
        for (var ii = 0; ii < messages.length; ii++) {
            $(errorDetail).html('').append("<li>" + messages[ii] + "</li>");
        } // for
    } // if
} // displayFieldErrors

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":input").focus(function(evt) {
        displayFieldErrors(this);
    }).blur(function(evt) {
        $("#errordetail_" + this.id).remove();
    });
    
    $("#taskentry").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // TO BE COMPLETED IN THE NEXT CHAPTER
        },
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            // initialise an empty errors map
            errors = {};
            
            // iterate through the jQuery validation error map, and convert to 
            // something we can use
            for (var elementName in errorMap) {
                if (! errors[elementName]) {
                    errors[elementName] = [];
                } // if
                
                errors[elementName].push(errorMap[elementName]);
            } // for
            
            // now display the errors
            displayErrors();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    min-height: 480px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

form ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 6px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

form ul li {
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    padding: 4px;
}
 
form ul li.naked {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

input, textarea {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    width: 99%;
}

input.invalid, textarea.invalid {
    background: url(exclamation.png) no-repeat 2px 2px;
    padding-left: 22px;
}

#errors {
    margin: 8px 6px 2px 6px;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.0, #cc0000), color-stop(0.7, #770022));
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}

ul.errors-inline li {
    border: 0px;
    color: red;
    padding: 0px;
}

input[type=submit] {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.0, #F8F8F8), color-stop(1.0, #AAAAAA));
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #333333;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px;
}

h1.simple {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 8px 4px 4px 8px;
    background: #333333;
    color: #AAAAAA;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #AAAAAA;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
}

h1.fancy {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.0, #666666), color-stop(0.5, #3A3A3A), color-stop(0.5, #222222), color-stop(1.0, #000000));
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #AAAAAA;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    margin: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Mobile Web Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="todolist.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="todolist.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 class="fancy">Christopher Hughes To Do List</h1>
        Hello World!
    <p>
        This is just the beginning!
    </p>
    <span class="highlight">
       More to come!
    </span>
    <h1 class="fancy">Create Task</h1>
 <div id="errors"></div>
    <form id="taskentry">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="text" name="task[name]" id="taskname" placeholder="Task Name"/></li>
        <li>
            <textarea name="task[description]" id="taskdesc" placeholder="Description" rows="5"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li><input type="text" name="task[due]" id="taskdue" placeholder="Task Due" /></li>
        <li class="naked"><input type="submit" name="Save" /></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you need help doing school work, as your instructor at the next lecture or go see him in person at his office (of course he won't answer your emails, he probably gets dozens every day :P)

Comment: It's online college, so there is no visiting him in person or calling him on the phone. I literally only have email to talk to him and he replies to everything I send with a sentence that has almost nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: Also, I THINK I figured out part of the problem. The code posted above appears to be linking the various javascript files as if they were local, but only the "todolist.js" is localized. The others are not local, but also there was no link given in my book to find them on the internet, and the version of jquery that is listed appears to be from 2010 so who even knows if it works anymore.

Comment: Yeah, and running the code snippet it can't find any of the files. A newer version of jquery might still work. You can see when resources aren't loaded when they appear red in the 'Network' tab of devtools (assuming you are testing your code in chrome).